# what's the fastest way to tell whether we're on a weekday in a particular hour range?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I am using PHP/MySQLin my project, and I have a table that holds time values, and days of week. The rows are SUNDAY_OPEN SUNDAY_CLOSE etc. for the rest of the week. These hold times like `9:00` and `17:00`.

All I want to do is on a certain time of access, to know whether the NOW() or time() in PHP fall exactly on that time range.

Comment: What type of column are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$day_of_week = strtoupper(date("l"));
$current_hour = date("G:i");
$sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS `open`
    FROM `schedule`
    WHERE '{$current_hour}' BETWEEN `{$day_of_week}_OPEN` AND `{$day_of_week}_CLOSE`";
```